# Carregar dados de um campo após pressionar um botão

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Preciso carregar dados de um campo de uma tabela.

Exemplo: Tabela (Modelo), a pessoa está preenchendo o formulário e quer utilizar no campo Texto esse modelo, e com isso ela clicaria em um botão (Carregar Modelo) e carregaria esse modelo no input Texto.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla ainda, você já fez alguma tentativa de fazer isso?Já tem a estrutura da tabela feita? Já tem algum modelo de como isso funcionaria? Precisamos de mais detalhes para poder te dar uma resposta que seja boa. Para melhorar sua pergunta você pode [edita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/19252/edit)-la

Comment: Sim, já tenho.O formulário funciona perfeitamente, apenas não consigo pensar em como carregar o modelo dentro do input quando o usuário clicar (Carregar Modelo), que esse modelo é um texto pronto apenas.

Comment: Acho que facilitaria responder se você editasse a pergunta para incluir os trechos de código relevantes do que você já tem pronto.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderá resolver isto com ajax, se você já fez os tão famosos campos select "Estado X Município", segue o mesmo raciocínio.

Ao clicar no botão acionará um evento que terá um ajax que apontará para um arquivo php, onde você pegará o parâmetro e com ele montará a consulta específica e retorna o dado do banco.

```
// cadastrarPaciente.js
$("#uf").on("change", function(){
    $.get("modulos/pacientes/ajax_listarCidade.php",
        {uf: $("#uf").val()},
            function(dados){
            $("#cod_cidade").empty();
            $("#cod_cidade").append(dados);
    });
});
```

```
// ajax_listarCidade.php
$PArray['uf'] = $_REQUEST['uf'];

$sql = "SELECT cod_mun, nome_mun FROM TMunicipio WHERE uf = '{$PArray['uf']}'";
...
```

É só seguir este raciocínio.